# Jquery function to update html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I am trying to do form validation via ajax.I get the form validation errors from the server as JSON and I am trying to catch them and display them appropriately using bootstrap alert div.Following is my function:

```
    // prepare Options Object for plugin
    var options = {
        beforeSubmit: function(form, options) {
            // return false to cancel submit
            block_form();
    },
    success: function() {
        unblock_form();
        $("#form_ajax").show();
    },
    error:  function(resp) {
        unblock_form();
        $("#form_ajax_error").show();
        // render errors in form fields
        var errors = JSON.parse(resp.responseText);
        for (error in errors) {
            $('#form_ajax_error').html("<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>"error"</div>");
        }
    }
};
```

However, this gives me an error on the console:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list**

at the following line

```
$('#form_ajax_error').html("<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>"error"</div>");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: missing `+` before and after `error`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to concatenate the `error` variable to the string using the `+` operator. Try this:

```
$('#form_ajax_error').html('<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">' + error + '</div>');
```